# not getting the ops array after inserting into mongo db

Tags: node.js

when am trying to move the image after inserting into mongo db using the function

```js
var db = require('../config/dbconnect')
module.exports = {

    //addProduct:(product,callback)=>
    addProduct: (product, callback) => {
        //console.log(product)
        db.get().collection('product').insertOne(product).then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            callback(data.ops[0]._id)
        })
    }
}
```

I am getting an error like:

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: new ObjectId("61054e43cffb994774d37ab0")
}
(node:6964) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at E:\Nodejs\ecommerce\helpdesk\product_help.js:11:27
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:6964) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6964) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: am not getting the ops[] array

Answer (score 1):

instead of `callback(data.ops[0]._id)`.

Try:

```js
db.get().collection('product').insertOne(product).then((data) => {
        callback(data.insertedId)
       
    })
    .catch((err)=>console.log('venk error',err))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is error first callback. Try the second argument which is the result.

```
 db.get().collection('product').insertOne(product).then((error,data)=>
       {
         console.log(data)
         callback(data.ops[0]._id)
       })
```

Comment: still not getting the ops array

Answer (score 0):

var db=require('../config/connection') var collection=require('../config/collections') module.exports={ addProduct:(product,callback)=>{ console.log(product); db.get().collection('product').insertOne(product).then((data)=>{
console.log(data); callback(data.insertedId)
}) } }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).